# How to mock a node module with jest within a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to mock the `DNS` node module in a class but I am unsure how to do so as it is enclosed in the class.  Here is a sample of what the class looks like...

```
import { lookup } from 'dns';

class Foo {
    // ...
    protected async _bar(IP: string) {
        // I want to mock "lookup"
        await new Promise<undefined>((resolve, reject) => {
            lookup(IP, (err, addr) => {
                if (err) reject(new Error('DNS Lookup failed for IP_ADDR ' + IP));

                resolve();
            });
        });

        // If dns found then return true
        return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I would like to create a test file `foo.spec.ts` that contains a test similar to the following:

```
import { Foo } from './Foo';

describe('Foo', () => {
    it('Bar Method returns true on success', () => {
        const test = new Foo();

        expect(test._bar('192.168.1.1')).resolves.toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I am unsure how to mock the `lookup` call within the class `Foo` given that the class definition is in a separate file from the test itself.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using `lookup` won't work since it doesn't return a `Promise`...

...but you can convert it to a version that does return a `Promise` by using [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

The code would end up looking something like this:

```
import { lookup as originalLookup } from 'dns';  // <= import original lookup...
import { promisify } from 'util';
const lookup = promisify(originalLookup);  // <= ...and promisify it

export class Foo {
  async _bar(IP: string) {
    await lookup(IP).catch(err => { throw new Error('Failed'); });
    return true;
  }
}
```

You could then mock `lookup` in your test using `jest.mock` like this:

```
import { Foo } from './Foo';

jest.mock('dns', () => ({
  lookup: (hostname, callback) => {
    hostname === 'example.com' ? callback() : callback('error');
  }
}))

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('Bar Method returns true on success', async () => {
    const test = new Foo();
    await expect(test._bar('example.com')).resolves.toBeTruthy();  // Success!
    await expect(test._bar('something else')).rejects.toThrowError('Failed');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Note that the mock needs to be created using `jest.mock` (and not something like `jest.spyOn`) since calls to `jest.mock` get hoisted and run first.  The mock needs to be in place before `Foo.js` is imported since the first thing it does is create and store the promisified `lookup`.

Comment: true on it wont work lol, I realized that after posting this morning but figured it would be good enough to get the point across, I updated the code above to fall more in line with the actual implementation within the src.  But I guess, jest doesnt care where the original footprint of the outside module is (in this case within the foo class)? It only cares that you notify it to use a spy or mock within the relevant test file?

Comment: simply adding `jest.mock('dns')` to the top of my test file did the trick.  I guess I read to far into the jest docs lol.  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

From jest's [tutorial](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks),

```
jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
  return function() {
    return {playSoundFile: () => {}};
  };
});
```

so you could do sth like `jest.mock('dns', () => ({ ... }));`